# Show that if $f$ is Positive-real function then $f=0$

Tags: analysis, lipschitz-functions

> Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ differentiable with $f(0)=0$ and :
>
> $$\forall x \in [0,1]: \quad |f'(x)| \leq M|f(x)|\quad ( M\geq 0) $$

- Show that if $f$ is Positive-real function then $f=0$

I think that Lipschitz continuity and Rolle's theorem can be useful here but i don't know how to use them here 
if $f$ is Positive-real function then  $$\forall x \in [0,1]\quad -Mf(x)\leq f'(x)\leq Mf(x) $$  which let us to write them in the following expression:

\begin{cases} M\exp(Mx)f(x)+\exp(Mx)f'(x)\geq 0 \\ -M\exp(-Mx)f(x)+\exp(-Mx)f'(x)\leq 0\end{cases}

Comment: The pair of inequalities at the end shows that the function $x\mapsto e^{Mx}f(x)$ is nondecreasing and the function $x\mapsto e^{-Mx}f(x)$ is nonincreasing. Both these functions are $0$ at $x=0$ hence one deduces that, for every $x\geqslant0$, $e^{-Mx}f(x)\leqslant0\leqslant e^{Mx}f(x)$. Can you conclude?

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grönwall%27s_inequality